# Filtering though a dataset with a dynamic definition

Tags: python, database

So I have a fairly large data set the looks like this:

```
data=[['O', '3C-1', '100', '100', '67.848600000000005', '0.00021722920782039196', '3.4565635', '1.3', '0.7', '0.38673693', '0.618034', '30.0', '-2.0097724299999977'],
['I', '1C-2', '150', '150', '101.77200000000001', '9.6548022169817182e-05', '3.46454077', '1.3', '0.7', '-1.77373911', '-1.70838786', '30.0', '-1.8860072499999994'],
['O', '3C-2', '250', '250', '169.62', '3.4757287981134192e-05', '3.48710222', '1.3', '0.7', '-6.81997504', '-3.94866255', '30.0', '-1.5686071800000005'],
['O', '3C-2', '500', '500', '339.23899999999998', '8.6893732236788835e-06', '3.23954068', '1.3', '0.7', '19.05924395', '2.15260466', '30.0', '-1.0255009299999993']]
```

I then have a definition that looks like this:

```
def mdata(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None):
    filt=[]
    for num,a in enumerate([a,b,c,d]):
        if a==None: continue
        filt.append([a,num])
    data=creader(open(stuff.csv'))
    for a,num in filt:
        data=[x for x in data if a in x[num]]
    for a in data: print a
```

a,b,c,d deal with the first four columns of the dataset. So if I call mdata() it returns the entire dataset, but if is specify data(a='O') it will only return the data in which the first column has an O.

This works fine except for columns c and d as they should be ints. EG if I specify mdata(c='10') I will get all datasets where the third column has 10 in it (100, 5103, etc). I could set a condition here to conditionally search through a string or convert the data in question to an int, but I have not been able to get the condition correct and it also seems like an extemely poor way to do this. How can this be improved upon?

Comment: What's IO,coord,n,m? They are not defined in this function.

Comment: I do apologize I was trying to generalize and missed those. It is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `list` to add the ability to map column names to subelements of each element, then provide a filtering mechanism.  The following will work just like a regular list, except that you won't be able to add an element if it doesn't have a `len` that is the same as the number of columns the list expects elements to have, and you will be able to iterate over elements in it filtered as you wish using `filtered_by()`.  Any column name provided to the initializer will be a valid argument name to `filtered_by()`.

```
class FilterableList(list):

    def __init__(self, column_names, initial_data=None):
        if initial_data is not None:
            list.__init__(self, initial_data)
        else:
            list.__init__(self)
        self.column_names = column_names

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if len(value) != len(self.column_names):
            raise ValueError('Rows must have the correct number of columns.')
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)

    def append(self, value):
        if len(value) != len(self.column_names):
            raise ValueError('Rows must have the correct number of columns.')
        list.append(self, value)

    def extend(self, values):
        for value in values:
            self.append(value)

    def filtered_by(self, **filters):
        try:
            filters = [(self.column_names.index(filter[0]), filter[1]) for filter in filters.iteritems()]
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('Tried to apply filter with invalid column name.')
        for row in self:
            for index, value in filters:
                if row[index] != value:
                    continue
                yield row

data = FilterableList(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
data.extend(((1,2,3,4), (2,2,5,6), (3,4,7,8)))
for row in data.filtered_by(b=2, c=5):
    print row
```

Comment: I get `yield row` , `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator` when I try to run this. I am not very familiar with classes (although this is teaching me quite a bit), do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Oops, that was my fault, sorry.  Need to `raise` exceptions, not `return` them...

Comment: This is a nice way of doing things, and I can extend this to do other things I need it do inside the class. You may have pushed me (fairly unwillingly admittedly) across the learning barrier to classes, I believe I will use these more in the future. Much obliged for the help.

Comment: You could also extend this pretty trivially so that your filters could be any arbitrary callable that expects a single argument (the value from the column in the row), in which case you could filter based upon any logic you want (in range, regex, or even something like returns valid result from another api).

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend having a look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

Here's the sort of thing which it makes very easy.

First, loading the data:

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv("op.csv", index_col=False)
>>> data
   0     1    2    3         4         5         6    7    8          9        10  11        12
0  O  3C-1  100  100   67.8486  0.000217  3.456564  1.3  0.7   0.386737  0.618034  30 -2.009772
1  I  1C-2  150  150  101.7720  0.000097  3.464541  1.3  0.7  -1.773739 -1.708388  30 -1.886007
2  O  3C-2  250  250  169.6200  0.000035  3.487102  1.3  0.7  -6.819975 -3.948663  30 -1.568607
3  O  3C-2  500  500  339.2390  0.000009  3.239541  1.3  0.7  19.059244  2.152605  30 -1.025501
```

Select a column, and find out which values are `"O"`:

```
>>> data['0']
0    O
1    I
2    O
3    O
Name: 0
>>> data['0'] == "O"
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: 0
```

Get only those rows:

```
>>> data[data['0'] == "O"]
   0     1    2    3         4         5         6    7    8          9        10  11        12
0  O  3C-1  100  100   67.8486  0.000217  3.456564  1.3  0.7   0.386737  0.618034  30 -2.009772
2  O  3C-2  250  250  169.6200  0.000035  3.487102  1.3  0.7  -6.819975 -3.948663  30 -1.568607
3  O  3C-2  500  500  339.2390  0.000009  3.239541  1.3  0.7  19.059244  2.152605  30 -1.025501
```

Group the rows by the first value:

```
>>> for val, rows in data.groupby("0"):
...     print val
...     print rows
...     
I
   0     1    2    3        4         5         6    7    8         9        10  11        12
1  I  1C-2  150  150  101.772  0.000097  3.464541  1.3  0.7 -1.773739 -1.708388  30 -1.886007
O
   0     1    2    3         4         5         6    7    8          9        10  11        12
0  O  3C-1  100  100   67.8486  0.000217  3.456564  1.3  0.7   0.386737  0.618034  30 -2.009772
2  O  3C-2  250  250  169.6200  0.000035  3.487102  1.3  0.7  -6.819975 -3.948663  30 -1.568607
3  O  3C-2  500  500  339.2390  0.000009  3.239541  1.3  0.7  19.059244  2.152605  30 -1.025501
```

And so on:

```
>>> data[data['0'] == "O"]["4"]
0     67.8486
2    169.6200
3    339.2390
Name: 4
>>> data[data['0'] == "O"]["4"].mean()
192.23586666666665
```

It's made my life very much easier.

Comment: Ah something built upon numpy. This looks great I will certainly give it a go.